# Create a Visual Studio 2010-like splash screen

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance, splash-screen

I was intending to create a [splash screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen) like the one sported by Visual Studio 2010 for my desktop application (feel free to use any version of C#/VB.NET/CLR).

[image: Visual Studio 2010 splash screen]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/visualstudio/WindowsLiveWriter/BehindtheScenesSplashScreen_CC39/image_4.png))</sub>

As per the Visual Studio blogs, the splash screen was not developed using [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) since it would involve the CLR and WPF libraries to load causing a substantial delay in application loading. Hence, they reverted to C++ and [Win32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) stack to do that same for performance reasons.

Is there a feasible option available for Windows Forms or WPF developer to leverage the same branding? The idea is to have similar rich branding in a splash screen without loosing performance and start-up time.

Using PNGs and transparency effects does not help on Windows Forms (a known issue, and I have read related questions on this site for that). Just to emphasise: it's a splash screen, so start-up time can't be compromised.

Comment: You answered your own question: "Using WPF would cause a substantial delay while the CLR and WPF libraries load".  WinForms requires the CLR and WinForms libraries, so it can't be much better and probably is worse.

Comment: CLR + WinForms is still quicker then CLR + WPF and all of us sort-of know the probable reasons. 
Was just wondering if some trick would give me both performance and rich branding without going for Win32 APIs.

Comment: I for one hate splash screens. Make your application load faster .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at *[Transparent Splash Screen](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/SplashScreen.aspx)*. Or *[C# Splash Screen](http://www.vcskicks.com/splash-screen.php)*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the resources.
Just a concern though: I understand Win32 APIs are the way out for these scenarios, but as my first preference, was wishing to avoid them.
Nonetheless, surely useful.

Comment: Totally accept your definition of "avoiding".
Was into VB6 development prior to .NET and hence have written descent bits of Win32 API code. Avoiding was not for skipping to learn the Win32 API but to try find a cleaner (managed, if you will) way of doing the same.

Answer (score 4):

The guys that wrote it actually did a post on it, *[Behind the Scenes: The Splash Screen](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006133350/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/11/11/behind-the-scenes-splash-screen.aspx)* (2009-11-10)...

Comment: Yes, I had read the post and thats the reason why i mentioned "As per the Visual Studio blogs".
Thanks for pointing the URI (i should have done that earlier)!

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar with a patcher for an [massively multiplayer online game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_game)  (MMO), and we like pretty splash screens in games. I made a custom ONLOAD event (instead of OnShown or Load event that both present a few inconveniences in this case) and put my code for displaying the pretty picture there:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs args)
{
    base.OnLoad(args);
    Application.Idle += new EventHandler(OnLoaded);
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender,
                      EventArgs args)
{
    Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(OnLoaded);

    // TODO: Add relevant code here
}
```

As for the picture, surely is there a way for displaying PNG files using native behavior (for partial transparency like in the Visual Studio splash screen).